# Having two <div> blocks aligned side by side - Wordpress website

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm creating a custom landing page for my employers website.

http://juniorgoldreport.com/welcome/ this is the landing page.

I'm just trying throw some idea's until we find something solid, so at the moment the landing page is extremely simple.

I'm having trouble splitting my body into two different div blocks.

```
<div class="welcome-landing">
  <div class="landing-header">
    <div class="logo-img">
      <img src="http://juniorgoldreport.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/logoo2.png" alt="junior gold report logo" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="landing-bar">
   <ul class="landing-nav">
     <li> <a href="http://juniorgoldreport.com/about-us/">About Us</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="http://juniorgoldreport.com/accredited-investors/" style="color:#cacaca">Accredited Investors</a> </li>
   </ul>   
  </div>

  <div class="landing-body">
    <div class="body-left">
      [layerslider id="11"]
    </div>
    <div class="body-right">
       TEST BLOCK
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="landing-footer">
     FOOTER TEST
  </div>
</div>
```

Where you see the "TEST BLOCK" is the block I'm having trouble with. I have a subscribe button in there right now when you look at it in the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove any character between two horizontal `Divs`

```
  <div class="landing-body">
    <div class="body-left">
    //content here
    </div><div class="body-right">     <-- </div><div> No character in between
    //content here      
   </div>
  </div>
```

add following `css`

```
.body-left, .body-right {
display: inline-block;
width: 50%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use
1) float:left
or
2) display:inline-block

for both blocks
http://c2n.me/3yr3jOw

Answer (score 0):

I'd make this a comment but I don't have enough points.

Try adding `float: left;` to your CSS for the `.body-left` div, and `float: right;` to `.body-right`.

Also, your `<footer>` tag should include `clear: both;`.

There's a lot more to be taken care of here, but this should get you on the right path.